# Layers move when using specific CRS

Tags: layers, lock, position

Using Google Satellite for a basemap and polygons (KML) drawn from Google Earth to create additional polygons using landscape features present on Google Earth and Google Basemap, within the original polygon shape.

I need to do all this using CRS WGS84/UTM zone 34S (EPSG 32724) as I was told this would give me co-ordinates that I can use for spatial statistics using R.

My problem is that when I set the project CRS to this, when I create new polygons and pan my map, the polygons move slightly out of place and will thus not be synchronized with whatever new polygons I create.

I tried using a different CRS and everything stays in place then, but this will not work with my statistics. Only when I use the WGS84/UTM zone 34S CRS, which I need, does everything move.

How do I set the CRS so that all my layers remain in position?

Please bear in mind I am not very familiar with GIS.